# iphone team development

Tags: iphone

I develop iPhone applications and some of managers want to have development snapshot version on their devices. Does anybody knows how make it in right way?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean by development snapshot version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they just want to test a dev build as the app is being developed, you can use the standard license and just distribute ad hoc builds. There is a [pretty good, quick guide on Kamran Kazempour's blog](http://kamran.kazempour.ca/blog/2010/05/21/iphone-ad-hoc-build/).

Comment: Making Ad Hoc Distribution certificates and builds is a fairly common process to let management try out an app in development.  Make sure whatever snapshots you pick for management are at least sanity tested recent versions, and not just the latest random checkin from source control.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to buy apple's ios developer enterprise license $299. see: ref § in-house distribution.

ref: http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/